# Complex Map with One Type Key but different Type Values using C++. (Not Multmap)

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to make one map like these conditions,

1) Total 50 String Keys.
2) First 40 Values are Strings.
3) Other 10 Values are integers.

like

```
//No idea how to initialize this map but after initialization
map2D["Key-1"]="Value-1";
map2D["Key-2"]="Value-2";
map2D["Key-3"]="Value-3";
........................
........................
........................
map2D["Key-39"]="Value-39";
map2D["Key-41"]= 123;
map2D["Key-42"]=234;
.......................
.......................
.......................
map2d["Key-50"]=24132;
```

Any idea how to achieve this goal. Thanks

Comment: Create an object that holds either a string or an int and insert that as the value.

Comment: You could use `boost::any` as the value type.

Comment: @kerrekSB...I want to do this with one map and without Boost Library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the class variant from the boost lib. Think of it as a union for non-POD types.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html

Here is an example from the webpage:

```
std::vector< boost::variant<int, std::string> > vec;
vec.push_back( 21 );
vec.push_back( "hello " );
```

So, the value type of your container could be `boost::variant<int, std::string>`.

Comment: Any idea without the Boost?

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view, both of tgmath's solutoins are correct, but I think you should rethink what you are trying to accomplish.  What is the purpose of having two different types in the map?  How will you actually be using the values?

Types in C++ allow you to use the compiler to choose what operations should be performed on the data represented by that type.  They serve a further very important purpose, which is communicating to the developer (maybe  another dev, maybe you later down the line) some meaning about what kinds of operations you expect to be doing with that data which the type is representing.

So what will you be doing with the values from your map?  If you will be using them in a calculation, you need a way to determine if your value is a string or an integer.  If you're getting a variant or a union, you'll have to test which value is actually represented before use.

If you will just be outputting the value, or other string-friendly operations, it's better from a design point of view to store a string.  If you performing an operation that must behave differently depending on whether or not you are using a string or an integer, then you might want to consider using inheritence -- create a class MapValue (use a more meaningful name), which has IntValue and StringValue inheriting from it.    The the compiler will use rtti to use the correct behaviour.

A union will have the benefit of memory efficiency and saving the (usually insignificant) rtti overhead.

Comment: Yep. Good point. It might help if you consider this. Also using two maps(as @Kerrek_SB suggested) is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without boost. Use a union and C++11. It allows non-POD members.
But be careful with the creation and deletion of strings to prevent memory leak.

```
union Compound {
    std::string str;
    int i;
    ~Compound() {}
};
```

A running example ho to use it: http://ideone.com/SUyyv1

Another thing: Both variables are stored in the same memory block. It can produce a segfault to read a `string` if only an `int` is given.
You could fix that by writing a class with two variables which knows whether it contains a `string` or an `int`.
If you write this a template version, it might end up to be a boost::variant equivalent.